# Proof about linear systems of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

If $X_1$,$X_2$ are solutions of $AX=B \neq 0 $ then $aX_1 + bX_2$ is never a solution.

I tryed this way:

From the hypotesis we have $AX_1=B$ and $AX_2=B$ with $B \neq 0$. Then:

$A(aX_1 + bX_2)=aAX_1 + bAX_2=aB + bB=B$ which is true only if $ a+b = 1$.

From what I found a linear combination can be a solution so I would like to know what is wrong with what I did.

Comment: What you have done is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true to say that $aX_1+bX_2$ is *never* a solution. For instance, consider $a=1$ and $b=0$. The question is whether $aX_1+bX_2$ is always a solution (i.e. for *any* $a$ and $b$). And the answer is clearly no if $a+b\neq 1$.